# Notepad website with shared texts and version control

Tags: website, notepad

I'm looking for a website that I used to visit a while ago. I can't find it anymore.
There I could share Text in Notepad style and people could edit this document. If I remember correctly it also had some sort of Version control.

Does anybody now this website?
If not could anybody introduce me to such a site?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is Etherpad. Here are a few instances of it:

http://titanpad.com/
http://piratepad.net/front-page/
http://etherpad.org/